# Remove Identity Insert from table Code First Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity, entity-framework-6

I suppose the title says it all. I have to change a table so that the ID PK column is no longer auto generated, so I can physically insert specific values.

Now the table is actually a composite key. Which is as follows;

```
    [Key,Column("driverId", Order=0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public override int ID { get; set; }

    [Key,Column("type", Order=1)]
    [ForeignKey("DriverType")]
    public int DriverTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual DriverType DriverType { get; set; }
```

Now I have added the DatabaseGenerated attribute and ran a migration which did create the following;

```
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.Driver");
        AlterColumn("dbo.Driver", "driverId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.Driver", new[] { "driverId", "type" });
```

i.e. the AlterColumn doesnt have the Identity bool in it.

However when I look at the make up of the table I have the following

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Driver] (
    [driverId]             INT                IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
```

Am I safe to just removd the IDENTITY (1,1)?

Answer (score 0):

To answer you question, no it is not safe to do that.

Add [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] to both parts of the key.

Comment: in core entity framework, migration does suggest to remove the column and re add in this situations.